# CSS Box-Model/ width set up

Tags: html, css

I am taking an MTA Certification test on Monday, I am using MeasureUp's practice test for HTML App Development practice exam, this is one of the questions, I have no clue how to answer this question,
(in Pixels):

```
  margin 5;
  border-width 5;
  padding 20;
  outline-width 5;
  width 470;
```

Which 2 css properties can you set to 10px so that the total box model width is set to 500px?

the actual answers: margin and border-width
how is that the answer?

Answers:

margin,
border-width,
outline-width,
padding

Answer (score 1):

`outline-width` and `border-width`

The width of a DOM element is equal to:

```
width + padding + border
```

`margin` is not included.

Besides, setting `padding` to 10px will not make the element's width 500px

You might want to read up on the [box model](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing).